# Python Selenium ActionChain does not work

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I followed the guide from [GeekForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/special-keys-in-selenium-python/), how to use `ActionChains` in selenium. Somehow nether their nor any other keys will perform. I need to download a pdf file via `ctrl + S` and it is not possible to do it otherwise (I checked it with many other people too).